# Handle HTTP POST multipart response through ServerSocket

Tags: java, http, multipartform-data, serversocket

Good afternoon everyone,

First of all, I'll say that it's only for personal purpose in a certain way, it's made to use for little projects to improve my Java knowledge, but my idea is to make this kind of things to understand better the way developers works with sockets and bytes, as I really like to understand this kind of things better for my future ideas.

Actually I'm making a lightweight HTTP server in Java to understand the way it works, and I've been reading documentation but still have some difficulties to actually understand part of the official documentation. The main problem I'm facing is that, something I'd like to know if it's related or not, the content-length seems to have a higher length than the one I get from the BufferedReader. I don't know if the issue is about the way chars are managed and bytes are being parsed to chars on the BufferedReader, so it has less data, so probably what I have to do is treat this part as a binary, so I'd have to read the bytes of the InputStream, but here comes the real deal I'm facing.

As Readers reads a certain amount of bytes, and then it stops and uses this as buffer, this means the data from the InputStream is being used on the Reader, and it's no longer on the stream, so using read() would end up on a -1 as there aren't more bytes to read. A multipart is divided in multiple elements separated with a boundary, and a newline that delimiters the information from the content. I still have to get the information as an String to process it, but the content should be parsed into a binary data, and, without modifying the buffer length, implying I'd require knowledge about the exact length I require to get only the information, the most probably result would be the content being transferred to the BufferedReader buffer. Is it possible to do it even with the processed data from the BufferedStream, or should I find a way to get that certain content as binary without being processed?

As I said, I'm new working with sockets and services, so I don't exactly know which are the possibilities it's another kind of issue, so any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific, the question is to broad. I would advise checking a simple but working open source server, for example https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd. By looking at working code you can understand how it works; then you can write your own.

Comment: @ewramner I wanted to know if someone had any clear idea from the start to go kinda faster, but I see the way is working this code, but it's still hard to read. At least the question about if I have to work with bytes since a start seems to be answered by this code so I'll try to understand it better and make my code, tysm

Comment: @RelampagoRojo since multipart data is both textual and binary, you are going to have to do your own buffering of the socket data so you have more control and know where the data switches back and forth. At the very least, since you can read binary data directly from a `BufferedInputStream`, and access its internal buffer, you can let it handle the actual buffering for you, and it is not difficult to write a custom `readLine()` method that can read a line of text from a `BufferedInputStream` without using `BufferedReader`.

Comment: You could also check https://github.com/erik-wramner/HttpClient (disclaimer - written by me). It is a client not a server and it is fairly dumb, but that is the point - fewer features and simple code makes it easier to see what is going on.

Comment: @ewramner thank you for your source. Mostly it'll become useful for me to read a little bit more about the HTTP standards so I can make classes for each element, meanwhile I'm still working on the reading process of the server, and actually I made the custom BufferedInputStream reader to include the readLine() method, and I was able to read it as a binary and retrieve the files from the Mutlipart content. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau), that can be found on the comments, which become useful for me:

> since multipart data is both textual and binary, you are going to have to do your own buffering of the socket data so you have more control and know where the data switches back and forth. At the very least, since you can read binary data directly from a BufferedInputStream, and access its internal buffer, you can let it handle the actual buffering for you, and it is not difficult to write a custom readLine() method that can read a line of text from a BufferedInputStream without using BufferedReader

Comment: I think that particular comment was from Remy Lebeau.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I'm not really used to Stackoverflow and I got kinda confused reading the names on the comments